# Keep the original path location when redefining window.console functions

Tags: javascript, console, instrumentation

I want to log all console messages so I redefined the console functions including log/warn/info/error as an example below

```
var originalError = console.error;    
console.error = function () {
     //Do something for logging
     originalError.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

However, I lost the original location where the console.error() is actually called: `path:line`, since it is now pointing to the `apply()` function in the code above. How can I get that information?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. However, you can simulate it by getting the `.stack` property of the error in your custom function, and pre/appending it to the error or logging it separately.

`(new Error).stack` gives something like:

```
"Error
    at <anonymous>:2:5
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)"
```

For non errors, use Stacktrace.js and get a stack trace of the arguments.callee:

https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js#generate-a-stacktrace-from-walking-argumentscallee

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is only throwable errors have stack trace. My purpose is to redefine console log/info/warn/error functions to do some extra work and definitely they don't have stack trace.

Comment: Get a stack trace from the `arguments.callee` using stacktrace.js: https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js#generate-a-stacktrace-from-walking-argumentscallee

Comment: This is the small part of stacktrace.js that walks the `arguments.callee` chain: https://github.com/stacktracejs/stack-generator - you don't need the whole thing :)